# Show $p\nmid k!+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory

**Question:** let $k$ be a positive integer, $p$ a prime number, such that $p=3k+1$, $r<p$ be a positive integer, such that $2^{k+1}\equiv r\pmod p$, and
$r\not\equiv 4,5\pmod 6$. Show that
$$p\nmid k!+1.$$

It is  well known
$$\left(\dfrac{p-1}{2}\right)!^2+1\equiv 0\pmod p$$
where $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, for my problem it seems hard to prove it.

Comment: I think better use of punctuation marks will help in understanding the question. Could you please edit the question so that it is easier to read (separate the sentences)?

Comment: What is the context for the question?

Answer (score 2):

It is known that each $p=3k+1$ has a unique representation of the form
$$
  p=\frac{L^2+27M^2}4,
$$
up to sign change; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_reciprocity#Primes_%E2%89%A1_1_(mod_3)):.

The same Wikipedia page cites Gauss's theorem:

> Under the same notation, we have $L\cdot k!^3\equiv 1\pmod p$.

**[EDITED AND EXTENDED]** As Geoff Robinson points out, this holds for an undetermined sign choice of $L$, so we need to work more; here it goes.

Assume now that $k!\equiv -1\pmod p$; this yields that $L\equiv -1\pmod p$, so either $L=-1$ or $|L|\geq p-1$. The latter cannot hold, as $4p<(p-1)^2+27$; so $L=-1$.

Thus, $4p=1+27M^2$. Writing $M=2m-1$, we arrive at the expansion
$$
  p=\frac{1+3M\sqrt{-3}}2\cdot \frac{1-3M\sqrt{-3}}2
  =\bigl((3m-1)+3\omega(2m-1)\bigr)\bigl((3m-1)+3\bar\omega(2m-1)\bigr)
$$
in the Eisenstein ring $\mathbb Z[\omega]$.

The number
$$
  \pi=(3m-1)+3\omega(2m-1)
$$
is a primary Eisenstein integer, hence by the cubic reciprocity law (see the same Wiki page) we have
$$
  \left(\frac2\pi\right)_3=\left(\frac \pi2\right)_3
  =\left(\frac{m+1+\omega}2\right)_3=:\alpha,
$$
We have $\alpha=\omega$ if $m$ is odd, and $\alpha=\bar\omega$ if $m$ is even.

If $m$ is odd, we have
$$
  r\equiv 2^k\equiv \omega
  \equiv\omega-(2\omega+1)\pi
  =\omega-(\omega-(9m-5))=9m-5\pmod \pi.
$$
Similarly, $r\equiv 9m-5\pmod{\bar\pi}$, and therefore $r\equiv 9m-5\pmod p$. Hence, $r=9m-5$ (notice that $9m-5<p$), and $r\equiv 4\pmod 6$. This is excluded by the conditions of the question.

If $m$ is even, we similarly get
$$
  r\equiv \bar\omega
  \equiv\bar\omega+(2\omega+1)\pi
  =-1-\omega+(\omega-(9m-5))
  =4-9m\pmod\pi
$$
and hence $r\equiv 4-9m\pmod p$, so $r=p+4-9m\equiv 5\pmod 6$. This is also excluded.

**P.S.** Pitifully, I have no access to that book, but Wikipedia claims that Gauss's theorem is Exercise 7.9 in Lemmermeyer's book:

> Lemmermeyer, Franz (2000), Reciprocity Laws: from Euler to Eisenstein, Berlin: Springer, ISBN 3-540-66957-4

Comment: Actually, footnote f to Article 358 of Disquisitiones Arithmeticae seems to say that the sign can't be determined, because it can be either according to the choice of a certain primitive root, so I am not sure you are justified in assuming $L$ positive.

Comment: Nice, can you link the Gauss's theorem proof,I searched for a while and found no proof of this theorem

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for the clarification --- I do not have access to the book. I've finished that case as well, and the modulo 6 congruence magically works!

Comment: @math110 I've added a PS about Gauss's theorem; sorry, I have no other information, maybe the communoty would help...

Comment: Exact wording of footnote f in DA: "Manifestly $M$ cannot be of the form $3z$ because otherwise $4n$ would be divisible by $3$. With regard to the ambiguity as to whether $b-c$ must $=N$ or $=-N$,it is unnecessary to consider the question here, and by the nature of the case it cannot be determined because it depends on the selection of the primitive root $g$. For some primitive roots the difference $b-c$ will be positive, for others negative".